Uvicorn is running but page keeps loading
I'm trying to run the app however, the page keeps loading.
app code:
from fastapi import FastAPI
app = FastAPI()
@app.get("/") async def root(): return {"message": "Hello World!"}

(venv) PS C:\Users\pc\Documents\fast-api-LMS> uvicorn main:app --reload
INFO:     Will watch for changes in these directories: ['C:\\Users\\pc\\Documents\\fast-api-LMS']
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://127.0.0.1:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:     Started reloader process [7468] using StatReload
INFO:     Started server process [26120]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.``

screenshot of the browser:
enter image description here
folder structure:

fast-api-LMS
├─ main.py
├─ poetry.lock
├─ pyproject.toml
├─ venv


Restarted the terminal
Set poetry Path


Have you tried disabling the watcher for changes in your working directory ?
